# How change color SpriteKit on touch SKSpriteNode

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

```
import SpriteKit

func + (left: CGPoint, right: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
  return CGPoint(x: left.x + right.x, y: left.y + right.y)
}

func - (left: CGPoint, right: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
  return  CGPoint(x: left.x - right.x, y: left.y - right.y)
}

func * (point: CGPoint, scalar: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
  return  CGPoint(x: point.x * scalar.x, y: point.y * scalar.y)
}

func / (point: CGPoint, scalar: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
  return  CGPoint(x: point.x / scalar.x, y: point.y / scalar.y)
}

enum Tile: Int {

  case Ground
  case Wall

  var description: String {
  switch self {
  case Ground:
    return "Ground"
  case Wall:
    return "Wall"
  }
  }

  var image: String {
  switch self {
  case Ground:
    return "ground"
  case Wall:
    return "wall"

  }
  }
}

class GameScene: SKScene {

  private var scaleOffset: CGFloat = 1.0
  private var panOffset = CGPointZero
  let viewIso: SKSpriteNode

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
  fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }

  var users = Array<Array<UserScore>>()



  let tileSize = (width: 32, height: 32)

  override init(size: CGSize) {
  viewIso = SKSpriteNode()
  super.init(size: size)
  self.view?.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
  self.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()


  let scores = [
    [10, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 7, 7, 6, 5],
    [10, 9, 9, 9, 8, 7, 7, 6, 5, 4],
    [9, 9, 9, 8, 7, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3],
    [9, 9, 8, 7,11, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2],
    [9, 8, 7, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 2],
    [8, 7, 7, 6, 5, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1],
    [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0],
    [7, 6, 5, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0],
    [6, 5, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
  ]

  for i in 0..<scores.count {
    let row = scores[i]
    users.append(Array(count: scores.count, repeatedValue: UserScore()))
    for j in 0..<row.count {
    var tileInt = row[j]

    var me = false

    if tileInt == 11 {
      tileInt = 8
      me = true
    }

    let user = UserScore(name: "Rinat-\(tileInt)", score: tileInt, me: me)

    users[i][j] = user
    }
  }

  }

  override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
  let deviceScale = self.size.width/667
  viewIso.position =  CGPoint(x: 200, y: 200)
  viewIso.xScale = deviceScale
  viewIso.yScale = deviceScale
  addChild(viewIso)

  placeAllTilesIso()
  }

  func point2DToIso(p: CGPoint, inverse: Bool) -> CGPoint {
  // invert y pre conversion
  var point = p * CGPoint(x: 1, y: -1)
  // convert using algorithm
  point =  CGPoint(x: (point.x - point.y), y: ((point.x + point.y) / 2))
  // invert y post conversion
  if !inverse {
    point = point * CGPoint(x: 1, y: -1)
  } else {
    point = point * CGPoint(x: 1, y: -1)
  }
  return point
  }

  func placeTileIso(image: String, withPosition: CGPoint, color: UIColor) -> SKSpriteNode {
  let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: image)
  let tileSprite = SKSpriteNode(texture: texture)
  tileSprite.position = withPosition
  tileSprite.colorBlendFactor = 1.0
  tileSprite.alpha = 1.0

  if color != UIColor.clearColor() {
    tileSprite.color = color
  } else {
    tileSprite.color = UIColor.yellowColor()
  }

  tileSprite.anchorPoint =  CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
  return tileSprite
  }

  func placeAllTilesIso() {
  for i in 0..<users.count {
    let row = users[i]
    for j in 0..<row.count {
    var tileInt = row[j].score

    let column = UserNode()
    column.name =  String(tileInt)
    column.colorBlendFactor = 1.0
    column.alpha = 1.0
    column.color = UIColor.yellowColor()

    if tileInt > 1 {
      tileInt = 1
    }

    let tile = Tile(rawValue: tileInt)!

    var color = UIColor.clearColor()

    if row[j].me {
      color = UIColor.redColor()
    } else {
      color = UIColor.clearColor()
    }

    if tileInt > 0 {
      let index = tileSize.height
        let xxx = (j*tileSize.width) + index * 0
        let yyy = -(i*tileSize.height + index  * 0)
        let pointxxx = point2DToIso(CGPoint(x: xxx, y: yyy), inverse: false)
        column.addChild(placeTileIso(("iso_" + tile.image), withPosition: pointxxx, color: color))
      if row[j].score > 1 {
      if j > 0 || i > 0 {
        for indexs in (0..<row[j].score) {
          let xx = (j*tileSize.width) + index * (-indexs)
          let yy = -(i*tileSize.height + index  * (-indexs))
          let pointxx = point2DToIso(CGPoint(x: xx, y: yy), inverse: false)
          column.addChild(placeTileIso(("iso_" + tile.image), withPosition: pointxx, color: color))
        }
      } else {
        for indexs in (1..<row[j].score) {
          let xx = -((j*tileSize.width) + index * indexs)
          let yy = i*tileSize.height + index  * indexs
          let pointxx = point2DToIso(CGPoint(x: xx, y: yy), inverse: false)
          column.addChild(placeTileIso(("iso_" + tile.image), withPosition: pointxx, color: color))
        }
      }
      }
    } else {
      let xxx = (j*tileSize.width) + tileSize.height * 0
      let yyy = -(i*tileSize.height + tileSize.height  * 0)
      let pointxxx = point2DToIso(CGPoint(x: xxx, y: yyy), inverse: false)
      column.addChild(placeTileIso(("iso_" + tile.image), withPosition: pointxxx, color: color))
    }

    column.userObj = row[j]
    viewIso.addChild(column)
    }
  }
  }

  override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
      let nodeAtTouch = self.nodeAtPoint(touch.locationInNode(self))
      if let parent = nodeAtTouch.parent as? UserNode {
        if let name = parent.name {
          if Int(name) != nil {
            print(parent.userObj)

            let changeColorAction = SKAction.colorizeWithColor(SKColor.blueColor(), colorBlendFactor: 1.0, duration: 0.5)
            parent.runAction(changeColorAction) {
              parent.color = SKColor.blueColor() //On completion of action, we set color so after in comparison method not have conflicts while comparing color components
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  func onPinchStart(centroid: CGPoint, scale: CGFloat) {
  scaleOffset = viewIso.xScale
  }

  func onPinchMove(centroid: CGPoint, scale: CGFloat) {
  viewIso.xScale = (scale - 1.0) + scaleOffset
  viewIso.yScale = (scale - 1.0) + scaleOffset
  }

  func onPan(gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
  let y = -(gestureRecognizer.locationInView(self.view).y - self.view!.frame.height)
  let x = gestureRecognizer.locationInView(self.view).x

  self.viewIso.position =  CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
  }

}
```

Method not change color:

```
  override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
      let nodeAtTouch = self.nodeAtPoint(touch.locationInNode(self))
      if let parent = nodeAtTouch.parent as? UserNode {
        if let name = parent.name {
          if Int(name) != nil {
            print(parent.userObj)

            let changeColorAction = SKAction.colorizeWithColor(SKColor.blueColor(), colorBlendFactor: 1.0, duration: 0.5)
            parent.runAction(changeColorAction) {
              parent.color = SKColor.blueColor() //On completion of action, we set color so after in comparison method not have conflicts while comparing color components
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: if you do not use parent.color = SKColor.blueColor()  it works?